# How do open an HTML file with a default application using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I have an HTML file `C:\Program Files\my_html_files\file.html`. How do I open this file using VBScript? (By "open" I mean open it with the default application, as if it was double-clicked in Explorer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean open the file in Internet Explorer?

```
Dim objIE
'' Create an IE object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'' Open file
objIE.Navigate "C:\Program Files\my_html_files\file.html"
```

Answer (score 8):

The following VBScript code does the equivalent of double clicking on the file.html and having the default open command occur for that file:

```
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\my_html_files\file.html"""
```

If you want to get really tricksy you can omit the variable declaration and write it in one line of code:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Program Files\my_html_files\file.html"""
```

N.B. Strings may require to be enquoted to handle paths containing spaces. This can be done using the `Chr(34)` suggestion by @aland or as I've done in my code examples.

Comment: You'll need to wrap the path with Chr(34) if there's spaces, e.g.

wshShell.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\my_html_files\file.html" & Chr(34)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\my_html_files\file.html" & Chr(34)`

Comment: There is a & missing. *Both* upvoter should be ashamed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [File System Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28VS.85%29.aspx) like this:

```
Set FSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set iFile = FSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\Program Files\my_html_files\file.html")
Data = iFile.ReadAll
MsgBox(Data)
iFile.Close
```

Comment: It not good
I need the action as double click on the file.html
Your script not display the real file.html